# ASP.NET MVC application failing to validate token received from Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, single-sign-on

I've being having trouble trying to get an asp.net mvc application to work with single sign on for a few weeks now. This is the first time I've worked with single sign on and azure ad authentication.  The single sign works with a single tenant azure ad.

The following code is set up to authenticate the user.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

    public static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

    // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
    string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net/";

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        FATContext db = new FATContext();

        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
               
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                        return authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                           code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);
                    }
                }
            });

    }
}
```

After signing in, the following error is received

```
 IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys:
 kid: 'xxx',
 token: "JWT"
```

I'm not sure at all how to complete the sign in request after receiving the token back from azure ad. I used fiddler to ensure the token is being sent back.

What is the best approach to this problem, Do I need to implement some code to decrypt the token? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could you please share the code that how you verify the tokens?

Comment: I scaffold-ed the code using connected services, do I need to verify the tokens with my own code? How do I get/call the token?

Comment: Can you share the part where you are verifying token?